# DialogResult requires two Clicks on OK when Form Modal

Tags: c#, modal-dialog, showdialog

I have a `Child form` which I need `Modal`, so of course I use `child.ShowDialog()` to make the form `Modal`.  While in this `form` if the user selects the `close/cancel` button they are prompted by a `DialogResult` asking if they are certain they wish to close.  The problem occurs when the user selects `OK` on the `DialogResult`.  It requires two clicks on `OK` for the `DialogResult box` to close.  I found that if I use `Dispose` as well as `Close` I can make the `child form` go away on the first click, yet the `DialogResult box` remains.  What am I missing in the code below that will allow the `DialogResult box` and `Form` to close after one click on `OK`?

```
private void closeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (calBackgroundWorker.IsBusy)
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("The Compass Calibration is already in progress, are you sure you wish to cancel?", "Stop Calibration", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            calibrationInProgress = false;
            calBackgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
            this.Dispose();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you subscribe to the `closeButton.Click` event twice?

Comment: So you have `MainForm`->`ChildForm` (modal)->`MessageBox`. On closing the `ChildForm`, you prompt a confirmation `MessageBox`. If the user selects `OK`, you want to close the `ChildForm`. Are you also wanting to close the `MainForm` as a result?

Comment: @SiLo I want to close the `ChildForm` which is `Modal` and the `MessageBox` which of course is `Modal` as well.  I do **not** want to close the `Parent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `SiLo` answer I was able to get much further, but only the `DialogResult` would close, not the `ChildForm`.  To allow both to be closed I needed to add `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK`.  The below code works perfectly for closing both `Modal` windows:

```
private void closeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (calBackgroundWorker.IsBusy)
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("The Compass Calibration is already in progress, are you sure you wish to cancel?", "Stop Calibration", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            calBackgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }
        return;
    }
    this.Close();
}
```

And the Event Handler:

```
void calBackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        this.Close();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes instead of btnYes.DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes. Fixed my problem as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First, you do not need the `Dispose()` call, `Close()` is sufficient. However, your `BackgroundWorker.CancelAsync()` call is not going to cancel the task immediately (synchronously). That is up to the implementation of `DoWork`, but you will still get a `RunWorkerCompleted` event which you can handle the cancelled status in.

You want something like this:

```
void closeButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(backgroundWorker.IsBusy)
  {
    var result = MessageBox.Show("...");

    if(result == DialogResult.OK)
      backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();

    return;
  }

  this.Close();
}
```

Then in your event handler:

```
void RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.Cancel)
  {
    this.Close();
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: This does close the `DialogResult` but the `ChildForm` does not close.

Comment: Also, I am using `if(e.Cancelled)` in the `event handler`